# Power Pivot: Setting up Data for Time-based Calculation Best Practice

Tags: powerpivot

I am just trying to figure out what would be most optimal to arrange my data.  I have a large data set (~1.7m rows)...analyzing data on 2,000+ 'stores' at a daily granularity...my fact table is set up something along the lines of:

**Date** | **Store_ID** | **Manager_ID** | **Other_IDs...** | **TY_Items_Sold** | **TY_Tot_Rev** | **LY_Items_Sold** | **LY_Tot_Rev...**

My question is:
*In order to calculate YoY sales data, is it more efficient to have it set up this way, where I have just TY's Date (YTD) and have 'TY' and additional 'LY' columns, or would it be better to have both years' dates? This would allow me to remove the 'LY' columns, but would double the length of my data set (creating a longer & skinnier data set)? Doing that would also allow me to make use of the DAX time intelligence functions...*

Or, alternatively (I don't think this would be the optimal way, but...), have a TY table, and a separate LY table (with TY dates) and set it up that way?

TY!

Comment: proper design is to have one column for items and one for revenue. Length of fact table should not concern you - power pivot is optimized to handle tall tables, and your data set is very small (large starts from 1 billion rows).

Comment: Thank you very much!